# Perl while loop doesn't restore the default input argument $_

Tags: perl, while-loop, iteration, parameter-passing

As the title says, I'm running into a case where $_ is NOT restored after iteration. For instance, piping an `echo foo` to the below...

```
$_ = 'bar';
print "$_\n";
while (<>) {
    chomp();
    print "$_\n";
}
print "$_\n";
```

outputs

```
bar
foo
```

but I expected

```
bar
foo
bar
```

Why is `$_` not restored back to what it was in the parent scope?

I did read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html, and at first, it wasn't clear why this was the case even after seeing the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perldoc perlsyn` says this about `foreach` loops:

> Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop.

whereas `while (<>)` ***assigns to*** `$_`, and does not make a similar guarantee.

`while (<>)` is the same as `while (defined($_ = <>))`.

I do not know of any part of Perl's documentation that might have led someone to assume that `$_` would be topicalized to in a `while` loop.

It is important to keep in mind that the behavior is not specific to `$_`. Every variable  is topicalized in a `foreach` loop, and none is in a `while` loop:

```
$ cat p1.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$foo = 'bar';

for $foo (qw(one two three)) {
    print "$foo\n";
}

print "$foo\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./p1.pl
one
two
three
bar
```

Compare that to:

```
$ cat p2.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$foo = 'bar';

while ($foo = <>) {
    chomp $foo;
    print "'$foo'\n";
}

print "'$foo'\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./p2.pl
one
'one'
two
'two'
three
'three'
''
```

By the time the last print is reached, `$foo` is undefined because the `while` loop was terminated following the assignment of an undefined value to `$foo`.

Comment: They actually do mention in the [perl doc for $_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) that `while (<>)` is equivalent to `while (defined($_ = <>))`. But that's as far as the perldoc went. Wish they could've mentioned that when the while loop scope closes, `$_` is not restored b.c. of the assignment....which I guess is pretty obvious now after reading your post then seeing the example they put up.

Comment: The thing is, every variable is topicalized when used in a `foreach` loop. With the `while`, no variable is. So, this is not specific to `$_`.

Comment: No, you should be iterating over handles with `while (my $line = <>)`

Comment: I was thinking of iterating handles from a Python perspective, so I brought up that I should use `for (<>)`. but if I was to do that in Perl I believe it loads up each line of the file into an in-memory list, then iterates over that list in the loop. But with `while (my $line = <>)` you only iterate once while saving memory (since you're not loading the contents in list context) and avoid corrupting $_.